# How to find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$ if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_0^{a_n} x^n dx=2$?

Tags: calculus

$\{a_n\}$ is positive sequence.

I tried to calculate the integral and got $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_n^{n+1}}{n+1}=2$, but I cannot continue.

Comment: Hint: What happens if $a_n \to a$ for $0 < a < 1$? How about if $a > 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** 
$$a_{n}= \sqrt[n+1]{\dfrac{a_n^{n+1}}{n+1}} \cdot \sqrt[n+1]{n+1}\\
\lim_n \sqrt[n+1]{n+1}=\lim_n \sqrt[n+1]{2}=1$$

**P.S.** If you are used to work with $\epsilon$, then
$$2-\epsilon < \dfrac{a_n^{n+1}}{n+1} < 2+\epsilon \Leftrightarrow \\
\sqrt[n+1]{(2-\epsilon)(n+1)} <a_{n}<\sqrt[n+1]{(2+\epsilon)(n+1)}  $$

Answer (score 1):

Then we have that $$a_n\sim (2n+2)^\dfrac{1}{n+1}\quad,\quad\text{for large enough }n$$which tends to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The integral equals $a_n^{n+1}/(n+1).$ Thus for large $n$ we have $1< a_n^{n+1}/(n+1) < 3.$ For such $n,$ we then have

$$(n+1)^{1/(n+1)}< a_n < [3(n+1)]^{1/(n+1)}.$$

Since the left and right sides both $\to 1,$ we have $\lim a_n = 1$ by the squeeze principle.